# Smooth infinitesimal analysis and law of excluded middle

Tags: smooth-functions, infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

I read about smooth infinitesimal analysis and I have several questions:

1. How to prove that in SIA every function on $R$ is continuous? (Every function whose domain is $R$, the real numbers, is continuous and infinitely differentiable.)
2. What does "$ε.1$" and "$ε.0$" mean in this proof? ([https://publish.uwo.ca/~jbell/basic.pdf](https://publish.uwo.ca/%7Ejbell/basic.pdf) , page 5-6)

[image]

3. For what purpose do we use Kock-Lawvere axiom when we deal with law of excluded middle? ([https://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/sdg.pdf](https://www.fuw.edu.pl/%7Ekostecki/sdg.pdf) , page 21)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It looks as if "e" is $\varepsilon$ which is epsilon.

Comment: @soupless Thanks. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means the product.  The point is that assuming the law of excluded middle would imply (by the argument given there) that
$$
(\forall \epsilon) \;\epsilon \cdot 1 = \epsilon \cdot 0.
$$
By the cancellation principle, we derive $1=0$.  This is the desired contradiction.  Therefore LEM cannot hold in the setting of synthetic differential geometry (a.k.a. smooth infinitesimal analysis).